# Enum Conversion to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dataset

I have created Enum of Leave Reason and now i want to convert it into string but error comes up.

Actually i want to bind data in grid view using data set and i am working in layers for this purpose.

i know my questions's answer will be in single line but i did not found exact solution from different sites that is why decided to ask here

please help coz i am new in c#

here is enum class in custom type layer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sherserve.CustomTypeLayer
{
    public enum LeaveReason
    {
        Sick,
        Planned,
        Other
    }
}
```

finally here is business logic layer :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sherserve.DataAccessLayer;
using Sherserve.CustomTypeLayer;
using System.Data;

namespace Sherserve.BusinessLogicLayer
{
    public class LMSManager
    {

        LMSRepository objLMSRepository = new LMSRepository();

        public void EmployeeLeave(EmployeeLeave LeaveInsert)
        {
            objLMSRepository.InsertLeave(LeaveInsert);
        }

        public List<CustomTypeLayer.EmployeeLeave> GetLeaveRecord(int emplid)
        {

            DataSet ds = objLMSRepository.GetLeaveRecord(emplid);
            List<EmployeeLeave> leavelist = new List<EmployeeLeave>();
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int a; a < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
                {

                    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[a];
                    EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave();
                    leave.DateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dt_from"]);
                    leave.DateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dt_to"]);
                    leave.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeID"]);
                    leave.Reason = Convert.ToString(dr["txt_reason"]);
                    //leave.LeaveType = Convert.ToString(dr["id_leave_type"]);
                    leavelist.Add(leave);
                }
            }
            return leavelist;
        }
    }
}
```

you can see in business logic layer that i have commented

```
leave.LeaveType = Convert.ToString(dr["id_leave_type"]);
```

actually LeaveType is enum and now i want to convert it into string so there should not appear any error....

Comment: Posting code directly from your application online might cause some problems if you are working for an organistaion

Comment: It looks as if the title of the question is wrong; you need a conversion FROM string to Enum

Comment: Vamsi Krishna may you please tell me how my code creates problem to post here???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Enum.Parse(Type,String,Boolean ignoreCase) or Enum.Parse(Type,String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) method.

```
leave.LeaveType=(LeaveReason)Enum.Parse(typeof(LeaveReason),
                                         dr["id_leave_type"].ToString(),true);
```

Comment: It helped me out but i think you forget to add true on last. i think the exact solution is   
leave.LeaveType = (LeaveReason)Enum.Parse(typeof(LeaveReason), dr["id_leave_type"].ToString(),true);

what u think???